# What tools available for Ubuntu are best suited for starting a FastCGI application, monitoring, and restarting if it stops?

Tags: fastcgi, daemontools, spawn-fcgi

Note:

- This is not in regards to PHP; Language is C++
- I will be using spawn-fcgi to launch the FastCGI application.

I've already found the supervise tool (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/supervise.8.html) provided by the daemontools package. However, I'm interested in other and/or better options.

Comment: What is wrong with supervise ?

Answer (score 1):

You may possibly want to look not using [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/).

There seem to be [several approaches](http://richard.wallman.org.uk/2010/03/monitor-a-fastcgi-server-using-monit/) to doing this, depending on implementation, but check around for something that suits your application.